# Как настроить права доступа к файлам для перезаписи php-скриптом?

Tags: php, macos

Пишу для себя простенький `php`-скрипт, который лезет по расписанию в конкретную папку на моем винте, читает размер изображений и если он больше `N`, перезаписывает изображения с резайзом.

Я пользуюсь `Mac OS X` и скрипт этот будет также работать в этой среде.

Файлы в этой папку (а это папка облака `Яндекс.Диск`) создаются с правами `644`.
Выходит изменять размер может только владелец. Само собой `Apache` у меня запускается пользователем `www-data`.

Тут у меня возникло несколько вариантов:

1. Просто поменять пользователя `Apache`. В одной из веток, которые я здесь создавал, писали, что с точки зрения безопасности это не лучший вариант.
2. Второй вариант - выставить `umask` как `002` (сейчас `022`), чтобы все файлы создавались с правами `664`. Тогда можно будет определить `www-data` в группу `stuff` и дело в шляпе. Опять же - насколько корректно с точки зрения безопасности такое изменение? И есть ли возможность выставить `umask` для конкретной папки?
3. Копать в сторону `ACL` (с ним я не сталкивался). Но что-то ругают эту систему, да и есть ли она в `Mac OS X` пока тоже не глядел.

Жду совета от специалистов, как лучше всего разрешить эту ситуацию.

Answer (score 1):

В Апаче есть обёртка для запуска cgi с правами других пользователей  [suEXEC](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html). Правда авторы там слишком намудрили с проверками, так что возможно проще написать простенькую программу на C самому, которая будет запускать ваш php-скипт, и поставить бинарному файлу s-бит с помощью `chmod u+s имяфайла`. Этот бит говорит системе, что файл нужно выполнять от имени владельца файла, к сожалению s-биты действуют только на бинарники.

Answer (score 0):

Групповая принадлежность — это обычная практика для доступа `http`-сервера к чужим файлам и каталогам.

Нужные права доступа к файлу можно устанавливать сразу после (или в процессе) сохранения файла.